# Getting data from nested map in dart

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to access avatar_url inside the map owner inside the list items.

**JsonMap**

[image]

Comment: does it coming from network (like Http.get) ?

Comment: yes
 https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=created:>2017-10-22&sort=stars&order=desc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
    import "package:http/http.dart" as http;

    Future<List<String>> getListOfAvatarUrl() async {
  http.Response response = http.get("your uri"));
  if(response.statusCode == 200) {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> items = jsonDecode(response.body)["items"];
    List<Map<String,dynamic>> owners = items.map<Map<String, dynamic>>((Map<String, dynamic> item) {
      return item['owner'];
    }).toList();
    List<String> avatarUrls = owners.map((Map<String, dynamic> owner) {
      return owner["avatar_url"].toString();
    }).toList();
    return avatarUrls;
  } 
  return [];
}
```

**Inside the build method**

```
return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
          // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
          future: getListOfAvatarUrl(),
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<String>> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Image.network(snapshot.data![index]);
                  });
            }
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ));
```

Comment: i want to access it inside Image.netwok( )?

Comment: Future fetchData() async{
    http.Response response;
    response=await http.get("https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=created:%3E2017-10-22&sort=stars&order=desc");
    if (response.statusCode==200){
      setState(() {
        mapResponse=json.decode(response.body);
        listOfFact=mapResponse['items'];
      }
      );
    }
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchData();
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  } children:<Widget> [
                      Image.network(),